# Create a synonym [osx-10.7] -> [osx-lion]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Our OS X tags usually use the version names instead of the numbers.

[osx-10.7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-10.7) should therefore be a synonym for → [osx-lion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-lion), just like [lion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lion) is.

Comment: couldn't understand the latter part of your question - ask it a separate question, please

Comment: @Sathya I had only noticed this missing synonym because of an invalid edit I rejected on the `osx-10.7` tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that the invalid edit was hyperlinked to meta question

Comment: @Sathya No worries, problem solved anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 10 rows affected
updating posts, 10 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [osx-lion] and [osx-10.7] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
```